# "MapQuest" Coding Challenge - Eliminate "Directions" That Cancel Each Other Out

Tags: javascript, arrays

The idea is to eliminate pointless travel in an array of directions:

`'N'` = North

`'S'` = South

`'E'` = East

`'W'` = West

So if we have the array `['S', 'E', 'W', 'W']`, we'll want for the `mapQuest` function to return:

`['S', 'W']`

Since **East** and **West** are next to each-other, they'll cancel each-other out.

***NOTE** The directions ***must*** be next to each-other in the array in order to get cancelled out.

Also, the array should *continue* to get reduced until the final array does *not* contain any opposites - i.e. it handles "complex cases":

`['W', 'N', 'S', 'E', 'N']`

should return

`['N']`

Because `['W', 'N', 'S', 'E', 'N']` => `['W', 'E', 'N']` => `['N']`

Part of this challenge is that I must use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

Based on my understanding of `.reduce()`, my thought is to do something like:

```js
function mapQuest (array) {
 return array.reduce((accumulator, current, i) => {
  if ((array[i] === 'S' && array[i + 1] !== 'N' && array[i - 1] !== 'N')) {
   accumulator.push(array[i]);
  }

  if ((array[i] === 'N' && array[i + 1] !== 'S' && array[i - 1] !== 'S')) {
   accumulator.push(array[i]);
  }
  
  if ((array[i] === 'E' && array[i + 1] !== 'W' && array[i - 1] !== 'W')) {
   accumulator.push(array[i]);
  }

  if ((array[i] === 'W' && array[i + 1] !== 'E' && array[i - 1] !== 'E')) {
   accumulator.push(array[i]);
  }
  
  return accumulator;
 }, []);
}

console.log(mapQuest(['S', 'E', 'W', 'W']));
```

Works but doesn't pass the last test-spec - handing complex situations.

Expect `['N', 'N', 'E', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'S', 'E']` to equal `['N', 'N', 'W', 'S', 'E']`

Comment: the check for undefined should be before checking the element. Also, [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is used for matching regular expressions. For equality comparison you can use just `current === 'S'`. That way you can also avoid the check for undefined.

Comment: @Slai - what would it look like to check for undefined before checking the element? I tried 

`if ((current !== undefined && current === 'S' && current[i + 1] !== 'N' || (current !== undefined && current === 'N' && current[i + 1] !== 'S'))) {
   accumulator.push(current);
  }`

Comment: no need for check for undefined. You just need `return accumulator;` after the if statements. Otherwise, the function returns undefined if nothing is returned, and `accumulator` becomes undefined for the next values. If you are not familiar with how reduce works, I would recommend starting with the basic for loops first. Also, your if statements don't seem to be handling all cases. I think you need at least two more.

Comment: @Slai I'm returning the accumulator now, and have 4 different if-statements which should be accounting for all "opposite direction scenarios". Something is still not working...

Comment: I think you are pretty close. Some of the logical operators are wrong, and the value should be pushed only if **all** of the conditions are met. It should be easier with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) rather than reduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution, though not very robust, is to assign the reduced array to a variable, and then reduce that array:

```js
function mapQuest (array) {
 let first = array.reduce((accumulator, current, i) => {
  if ((array[i] === 'S' && array[i + 1] !== 'N' && array[i - 1] !== 'N')) {
   accumulator.push(array[i]);
  }

  if ((array[i] === 'N' && array[i + 1] !== 'S' && array[i - 1] !== 'S')) {
   accumulator.push(array[i]);
  }
  
  if ((array[i] === 'E' && array[i + 1] !== 'W' && array[i - 1] !== 'W')) {
   accumulator.push(array[i]);
  }

  if ((array[i]=== 'W' && array[i + 1] !== 'E' && array[i - 1] !== 'E')) {
   accumulator.push(array[i]);
  }
  
  return accumulator;
 }, []);
 let second = first.reduce((final, current, index) => {
  if ((first[index] === 'S' && first[index + 1] !== 'N' && first[index - 1] !== 'N')) {
   final.push(first[index]);
  }

  if ((first[index] === 'N' && first[index + 1] !== 'S' && first[index - 1] !== 'S')) {
   final.push(first[index]);
  }
  
  if ((first[index] === 'E' && first[index + 1] !== 'W' && first[index - 1] !== 'W')) {
   final.push(first[index]);
  }

  if ((first[index] === 'W' && first[index + 1] !== 'E' && first[index - 1] !== 'E')) {
   final.push(first[index]);
  }
  
  return final;
 }, []);
 return second;
}
console.log(mapQuest(['N', 'N', 'E', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'S', 'E']));
```

Passes all test-specs.

Answer (score 1):

I offer you this code snippet as a possible answer. Here is what I did:

1. I used standard comparisons instead of `match`
2. I added additional `reduce` parameters
3. I used a recursive format to make sure the reducing happened to final answer
4. I used a rather unconventional method of removing the pairs by marking them for delete `'X'` and then filtering them out

```js
function mapQuest(quest, last) {

  if (JSON.stringify(quest) === JSON.stringify(last)) return quest;

  var initialQuest = quest.map(x => x);

  var newest = quest.reduce((accumulator, current, index, array) => {
    if ((current === 'S' && array[index + 1] === 'N') ||
      (current === 'N' && array[index + 1] === 'S')) {
      accumulator[index] = 'X';
      accumulator[index + 1] = 'X';
    }
    if ((current === 'E' && array[index + 1] === 'W') ||
      (current === 'W' && array[index + 1] === 'E')) {
      accumulator[index] = 'X';
      accumulator[index + 1] = 'X';
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, initialQuest);

  var filtered = newest.filter(i => i !== 'X');

  return mapQuest(filtered, initialQuest);
}
var tests = [];
tests.push({
  input: ['S', 'E', 'W', 'W'],
  expected: ['S', 'W']
});
tests.push({
  input: ['W', 'N', 'S', 'E', 'N'],
  expected: ['N']
});
tests.push({
  input: ['N', 'N', 'E', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'S', 'E'],
  expected: ['N', 'N', 'W', 'S', 'E']
});

tests.forEach(test => {
  var output = mapQuest(test.input, []);
  var passed = JSON.stringify(test.expected) === JSON.stringify(output) ? 'passed' : 'failed';
  console.log(`${test.input} => ${output} : ${passed}`);
});
```

Comment: Almost had it. Updated code to handle array reference issues when comparing and copying. Thanks!